# Get string of item from checkboxlist

Tags: c#, winforms, checkboxlist

I wante to do something like this.

```
String s = "";
foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.Items)
{
        s = checkedListBox1.Items(item).tostring;
         // do something with the string
}
```

I want to have the `string` of the item which is in the list box.

How can I get it runnig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't try it yet but I think this should work.

```
string s = "";
foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.Items)
{
        s = item.ToString();
         // do something with the string
}
```

Comment: I just forgot the () in my tests ... sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
string  s = "";
foreach (string item in checkedListBox1.Items)
{
   s = item;
   // do something with the string

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is this:

```
foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.Items)
{
    checkedListBox1.GetItemText(item);
}
```

Probably not the most useful, but [here is the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext.aspx) for it.